# Bacon.js and RxJS with Express.js and Mongoose.js

Tags: node.js, express, functional-programming, mongoose, bacon.js

I'm using Bacon.js on the server side with Express.JS (version 4.x)

This method never responds! Am I doing something extremely wrong here?

```
var User = require('../data/User');
var Bacon = require('baconjs').Bacon;

module.exports = function(router){
       router.route('/users').get(function(req, res){

           var result = Bacon.fromNodeCallback(User.find, null);

           result.onValue(function(docs){
               res.status(200).send(docs);
           });

           result.onError(function(err){
               res.status(500).send(err);
           });

    });
};
```

Apparently I'm failing with RxJS as well...

```
var User = require('../data/User');
var Rx = require('rx');

module.exports = function(router){
    router.route('/users').get(function(req, res){

        var query = Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(User.find)();

        query.subscribe(function(docs){
            res.send(docs);
        }, function(err){
            res.send('Error: ' + err);
        }, function(){
            console.log("COMPLETED");
        })

    });
};
```

This is the error that is returned:

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'discriminatorMapping' of undefined
```

Comment: This looks ok. Is the `null` parameter intentional? Do you mean to call User.find with null as in:
`User.find(null, function(err, docs) { ...`

Comment: Yes I put that null in there to test giving it an optional parameter.

Comment: And `User.find` works as expected? Basically, if you skip bacon completely and just write `User.find(null, function(err, docs) { if(err) { res.status(500).send(err); } else { res.status(200).send(docs); }})`, does that work?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly fine with the normal API

Comment: Could this be a problem with binding `this`? You could try giving `User.find.bind(User)` instead of `User.find` as the parameter.

Comment: Wow that worked perfect. This also worked: Rx.Observable.fromPromise(User.find({}).exec());. However, both of these syntax look extremely unfriendly and overkill.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66406/discussion-between-max-alexander-and-ollim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Bacon.fromNodeCallBack](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#bacon-fromnodecallback-object) with an object:

`Bacon.fromNodeCallback(User, "find", null);`

That will bind `this` correctly for your code.